# Is it important for me to delete the remaining registries of anaconda if I want to re-install it?

Tags: python, anaconda, registry, uninstallation, reinstall

I want to re-install anaconda because I failed to open the anaconda navigator after trying many methods.
So I installed anaconda-clean and used the uninstall.exe, deleted the remaining file folders in Programdata and C:\Users\Jossy .

Should I delete the remaining registries of anaconda, including:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
\Device\HarddiskVolume3\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
```

Is it okay for me to re-install anaconda now?

My environment is Windows10 64bit

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing all the related exe files before reinstalling Anaconda.
Anyhow, keeping them as it is makes no difference which means there is no data associated with those files. You can go on and delete those exe files and install anaconda afresh.
And to uninstall Anaconda, you can do it from "Add or Remove programs" in the Start Menu of Windows.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a million!